# Gulp and Browserify turn my React Redux into a huge file even though I removed the React dependencies

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs, redux

TL;DR: I'm getting build files that are way too big. I want them to be small and use the React source files from a CDN.

My Gulp file contains this:

```
gulp.task('build', () => {
    browserify({
        entries: dirs.src + '/index.jsx',
        extensions: ['.jsx'],
        debug: false
    })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
        presets: ["es2015", "react"]
    }))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.dest));
});
```

And said `index.jsx` file contains:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import slides from './stores/slides';

const store = slides();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('target')
);
```

React Redux is pretty small. And if I remove that part from the latter file the result is a mere 1 KB in size. Otherwise it'll turn into 700Kb+.

I already removed these two lines from that file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Because I wanted to load React and ReactDOM from a CDN. Why are my files still this incredibly large?

Comment: Make sure you don’t have `devtool` in the production Webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using the development version of React. You have to build your own production version, for that the `process.env.NODE_ENV` flag has to be set to `production`.

If you're using browserify, you need envify: https://github.com/hughsk/envify

`npm install envify --save-dev`

Your Gulpfile.js

```
var envify = require('envify/custom');

//...

.transform(babelify.configure({
    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
}))
.transform(envify({
    NODE_ENV: 'production'
}))

//...
```

More resources: http://dev.topheman.com/make-your-react-production-minified-version-with-webpack/

Comment: Not sure I follow, but I implemented your answer and the files are still huge. They still contain a full build of React and the ReactDOM. I don't want either of them and don't understand where they're coming from. It looks like Redux is adding all of it...

Comment: You need to add `uglify` at the end of your transforms, which will minify all the bundle and drop the dead code. It should be something like `.tranform(uglify())` and you get the `uglify` from `gulp-uglify` (there are tons of posts about that)

Comment: I know uglify, but I don't want my code uglified: I just want my components code. Not the entire React library. I'm loading Ready through script tags from a CDN. I don't want to have the entire React codebase in my own local project files... And, it's on development... I don't want uglified code on dev, just in production.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm loading Ready through script tags from a CDN. I don't want to have the entire React codebase in my own local project files.

In this case, your production Webpack config should specify React in `externals` config option:

```
{
  // ...
  externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
  },
  // ...
}
```

Otherwise Webpack will bundle it.

Also verify that you don’t have a `devtool` option in the production config. It can bloat the code immensely if you use `'eval'` or even inline sourcemaps.

> I know uglify, but I don't want my code uglified

You *should* be using uglify for your code in production. This is the only way to have small builds.